# Connected metric spaces

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X=[0,1)\cup[2,3]$, together with the "subspace metric from the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$" (I assume this is just the modulus then, since $n=1$?).

I am trying to show that $X$ is *not* connected. That is, there exists a set $A$ (which is neither $X$ or $\emptyset$) that is simultaneously open and closed in $X$.

I am struggling to find such a set, since $[0,1)$ is neither open nor closed on $X$ and so the same applies for $[2,3]$. If I take some closed interval $(a,b) \subset X$ then that would be open, but its complement would be the union of some other interval and some singleton sets of one integer, which would not open and so $(a,b)$ would not be closed.

If someone could point out where I'm going wrong/what I'm missing that would be great - I have spent a long time on this with no breakthrough.

Comment: What makes you so certain that $[0,1)$ isn't open in $X$?

Comment: “Open” in $X$ and “open” in $\mathbb{R}$ are not the same thing. A set $A \subseteq X$ is open in $X$ if there exists an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A = U \cap X$. With that in mind, you should take another look at the two intervals comprising $X$.